# How to create an array of variables generated within a loop in C programming

Tags: c, arrays

Within C programming,

I have an outer loop that cycles through index i=1,...,N. Within this loop there is another loop that for each i produces a variable x. For different values of i, x will change. How do I store these values before the next update of the index i, such that at the end of the i loop, I have a set of x values, one for each value of i, that I can then form into an array?

```
for(i=0,i<=N,i++)
{ 
{loop that produces a value of variable x for a given value of i};
};
```

Later in my code I wish to use an array of each value of x for a given value of i, `x[i]`.

I am very new to programming so your help is very much appreciated, thank you, apologies if it is a trivial thing, it is non-trivial to me I assure you.

Comment: you can use a 2d array

Comment: I see no attempt made at a solution.

Comment: @Tdorno Allow me to update my question, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

> Later in my code I wish to use an array of each value of x for a given value of i, x[i].

That's the answer right there -- make `x` an array instead of a single value, so that you can store different values for each `i`:

```
int x[N];
for(i=0,i<N,i++)
{
    x[i] = i^2;  // some computation of the ith value of x, i^2 just an example
}
```

Now `x` is an array of `N` elements, each with some value calculated in the `i`th iteration of the loop.

Comment: Aw man is that all! I have been struggling with this for ages! Thank you very much, will this array be populated each time i run the outer loop?

Comment: There's only one loop here, and yes, it will populate the array `x` every time your run the loop. And again, just to be clear, `i^2` is just an example of some computation based on `i`, since that's what you seem to want to do. Insert your own computation there. The important part is that `x` is an array, and `x[i]` is the `i`th element of `x`.